# Reassign reference returned by a method

Tags: java, c++

I have the following code:

```
 public class Foo  {
     Bar mineBar;
     class Bar  {
         int a;
         public Bar(int a)  {
              this.a=a;
         }
     }

     Bar getBar()  {
         return mineBar;
     }

     void reassingBar()  {
         //getBar()=new Bar(10);   //doesn't work
         mineBar=new Bar(10);
     } 

     public static void main(String[] args)  {
     }
}
```

Thee question is, if `getBar()` returns `Bar` then why can't I just use that returned `Bar` and reassign it a reference to a new object?
I wonder if it's different in C++?

Comment: This is actually invalid Java afaik.

Comment: Because you can only assign to a variable (or a field, or an array element) in Java. That's just how the language is defined.

Comment: Please remove the C++ tag.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, Fixed that.

Comment: @Andy Turne, Is it possible in C++ or some other language? How does it happen internally? There is, after all, a reference to a memory on the left, how does compiler know it is not a variable?

Comment: *"how does compiler know it is not a variable?"* Because it ___obviously___ isn't. The compiler is not blind and sees that this is a method call and not a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply how Java is specified. From [JLS Sec 15.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26), the grammar of the assignment is given by:

> ```
> Assignment:
>     LeftHandSide AssignmentOperator Expression
>
> LeftHandSide:
>     ExpressionName 
>     FieldAccess 
>     ArrayAccess
> ```

So the LHS has to be either a variable, a field or an array element. Anything else is invalid syntax.

The reason why you can't reassign a method's return value is because Java is pass-by-value, always. The "reference" returned by the `getBar()` method isn't the `Foo.bar` field, it's a effectively new variable which also points to the same object as the `Foo.bar` field. So, reassigning *that* variable has no effect on the value of the `Foo.bar` field.

And since that "variable" would only exist while the expression is being evaluated, there is no point in allowing it: you may as well just use the RHS's value directly instead.

It's no different from the following:

```
Object a = new Object();
Object b = a;      // a and b now refer to the same object.
b = new Object();  // This reassigns b, but not a.
```

Comment: I see. I've been thinking of Java references as of C++ pointers. It looks now the only way to make a variable to point at another memory address is to be able to make a direct reassignment like `variable=newValue`, isn't it so? So we can only change public variables here, while in C++ we can change any variable if we have its memory address?

Comment: Java references *are* like C++ pointers. But all you can do with a pointer is to point it to a different value, or dereference it. If you're thinking of something like `*p = 5` to change a "pointer", `*p` isn't a pointer, it's a reference. And there are no C++-style references in Java.